how define version of the solution to all projects?
I'm working on a Visual Studio 2022 solution with 12 DLL projects.
I want to efficiently update the version number to the same value across all projects,
avoiding individual modifications.
Are there any recommended approaches to achieve this centralized versioning management?
I didn't try to is on any way because i don't know how do it


Create a new file named Directory.Build.props in the root directory of your solution.

Open the file and add the following XML content
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
       <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
       <FileVersion>1.0.0.0</FileVersion>
       <AssemblyVersion>1.0.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>



